# How to test FCM using Postman/curl with Angular 8

Tags: angular, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to setup notification for my web application(Angular 8)using web-push.

I've already used angular service worker to successfully register the users 
endpoint, p256dh, and auth. It is on the database already.

My backend is Laravel, however, after setting up everything it didn't work.
So I am trying to setup a "raw" request with postman to teste if the notification itself is working before troubleshooting the backend.

(Tutorial I followed for the frontend: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/)

Here is the json on postman:

```js
{
   "to": "<HERE GOES THE USERS p256dh>",
   "notification": {
    "body": "Hello",
    "title": "This is test message."
   }
}
```

Url: ~~POST ~~

With the following headers:

```
Authorization: key=4uAH6X9MLTQWYWuDuUjBDk5P8OHPmFLWF9FZJeDAZMo (I've tried users auth code and also my VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY
Content-Type: application/Json
```

And I got the following response:

```
sender is not authenticated.
```

EDIT: Tried : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
and got:

```
Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.
```

What am I doing wrong? The result expected would be a notification even with the browser closed.

(I am testing o locahost and serving via angular-http-server , built with ng build --prod)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64286535/5959404 if you want to send it direcly from angular

Answer (score 1):

As the fcm response indicates, it looks like you are using the legacy server key for authentication. Legacy server keys are much shorter than the new server keys.

To fix this, use server key if you already have one or click add server key to create one and use this instead of the legacy server key in your authorization header.

See this [image](https://miro.medium.com/max/2044/1*0AL08M_uQXthZ23ycCAPZw.png) for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I already solved the "testing" using npm's web-push , passing the tokens and keys and the payload. Seems like my backend isn't doing its job properly, but that is a problem for a next question.

Comment: Great! :)
What was causing the issue? Was it the server key?

Comment: It was the way angular's service work expected the payload.
It expected a stringfied json with the "notification" key on it.

Answer (score 0):

I already tested using npms send-notification:

```sh
  web-push send-notification --endpoint=<url> [--key=<browser key>] [--auth=<auth secret>] [--payload=<message>] [--ttl=<seconds>] [--vapid-subject=<vapid subject>] [--vapid-pubkey=<public key url base64>] [--vapid-pvtkey=<private key url base64>]
```

Now is problem with the backend, which I will try to fix.