# sending POST request to FCM not accepting authorization header in angular

Tags: angular, post, firebase-cloud-messaging, authorization, httprequest

So I'm trying to use FCM to send notifications from Angular web application to mobile app using Firebase cloud messaging..

but I'm getting 401 response  "the request was missing an Authentication Key",
I tested the the same request on POSTMAN and it was working but on angular it is not..

here is my my code :

```
pushNotification(title , body){


this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' , {
  header: {
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization' :  'key='+ environment.cloudMessages.serverKey
  }, 
  body: {
    "notification": {
      "title": title   ,
      "body":  body,
      "mutable_content": true      
      },
      "priority":"high",
  }
}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
})

}
}
```

Where my key is the server key from cloud messaging..

Comment: this is happen to me too, did you fix the problem?

Comment: I used expo to send the notifications instead, but was getting the same error as well, but then i fixed it by using node js server to make the request instead of making it directly from my angular app..

Comment: thx dude i have to use node js server too

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the headers in as options parameter on the post.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'key=' + FB_MSG.serverKey
});
let options = {
  headers: headers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Interfaces containing payload
export interface FCMData {
  body: string;
  title: string;
}

export interface FCMPayload {
  to: string;
  collapse_key: string;
  data: FCMData;
}

// this method sends the notification
  async sendNotifications(message: string) {

    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'key=' + AppSettings.SERVER_TOKEN
    });
 

      const data: FCMData = {
        body: message,
        title: 'Sup!'
      };
      const fcmPayload: FCMPayload = {
        to: reg.token,
        collapse_key: 'type_a',
        data
      };

      this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' , fcmPayload , {headers}).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    );
  }
```

To Receive the Data Payload in Kotlin,
Inside your FirebaseMessagingService -> override fun onMessageReceived

```kotlin
 if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
    const body= (remoteMessage.data as ArrayMap).valueAt(0)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Service:-
token='key=AAAA7SRV_tKJ1NzRT8d2VJ5NGkayEx1HT9SxrdTT5G5a4kx5c6GoDvmWmzhCTWDRCqrdACrctF5Gjy5Df2qf6ZCNJHt7oHfH7BC'

createNotification(data) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.token
    });
    console.log('Res from Frontend=>', data)
    return this.http.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data, { headers: headers }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('Res from APi', res)
    })

  }


In component.ts:-
const fcm = {
        "notification": {
          "title": '',
          "body": '',
          "sound": "default",
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
          "icon": "./../../assets/images/logos/arabic-purpal-logo.png"
        },
        "data": {
          "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messagin  hbhj g Device Gr new v Message!",
        },
        "to": 'FCM Token Here'
      };
      this.service.createNotification(fcm)
    }
```